# Dynamically Load Choropleth using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, graphic

I have a database and web server filled with values for particular countries.  I want to be able to display an interactive map that is color coded based on the values from my database upon querying it.  (By interactive, I mean a simple zoom-in and move-around feature is all that is needed).

I have the shape files (.shp) of the world, and can easily get KML files as well.  This all needs to be done in JavaScript/JQuery (using JQuery to grab the data from the database) and then apply a color code scheme to the shape file (fill in the country borders).

What would be a good JavaScript library to use for this?  I have looked into OpenLayers but am unsure it can do what I need (perhaps I haven't dug deep enough).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [Leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com) would be another great option for you. Making choropleth maps in Leaflet is very easy and intercity (zooming) is standard.

Comment: This looks quite nice - I'll have to check it out!

Answer (score 0):

You might try D3.js, which is a great framework in general, and has some basic Choropleth support, though I'm not sure how well it works natively with your existing files.

Check out:

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/choropleth.html

Comment: I've looked at D3 as well - it lacks some of the features I'm looking for, and I did have a difficult time with my file formatting as well with this library.